# How to take screenshot of a tab in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am adding screenshot support to my extension, I want to take screenshot of a tab when a specific event is triggered, for example, a url is accessed. Now I am able to take screenshot of current tab using chrome.tabs.capturevisibletab, but the problem is that the event can be triggered by a tab that is not currently visible. So instead of visible tab, how can I take screenshot of any specific tab?

Comment: Look for examples of using chrome.debugger API with Page.captureScreenshot command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name is clear: capture**visible**tab.

You can put the focus on the tab you want to snapshot, invoke the method and the restore the focus on the previous tab though.
You will need to add the **<all_urls>** permission in your manifest file.

Comment: Yes captureVisibleTab cannot do it, is there any other API that can do it? Or do you mean it is impossbile to take screenshot of an invisible tab without activate it?

Comment: There is no API ready in your browser. You can try to take a look at several js library on the net. The first I get in my mind is "html2canvas".
Mozilla has tabs.captureTab if you want to develop a firefox addon.
Good luck